# How to write API for following web application?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, web-applications

My job is to write an API for my web application which is using another website authentication. I know very basic of javascript and PHP and HTML. I need some help to show me the path to write the API for this website.

Here is a link to the documentation of the website:

https://affinitylive.jira.com/wiki/display/APIS/Web+Applications

As it says, I must send this URL to get token->>>

```
https://hq.local.affinitylive.com/oauth2/v0/authorize?
scope=read(all)&
state=page_two&
redirect_uri=https://app.com/oauth_callback&
response_type=code&
client_id=34ad67fa2f@hq.local.affinitylive.com
```

and then after I got the token

```
POST /oauth2/v0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: hq.local.affinitylive.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic {client_id}:{client_secret}

code=frLA0s1m_D&

redirect_uri=https://app.com/oauth_callback&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

What I am not really sure and I love to learn is how this communication between my website and their website for authentication will be made. If the answer is wrong I wish to find a way to learn this more. Any guide or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: *[...] I know very basic of JavaScript, PHP and HTML [...]* - this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many methods to do this.
The below url will give you good information about them.

```
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html
```

And to achieve this, we can use javascript/php (example). In javascript we can make ajax calls to send the request. In php we can use curl to achieve the same.